# set position in a table

Tags: html

How to set position inside a table? I have table inside which I have span and certain links. I made `<td>` as center alignment and span texts starting from center, but when I do the same for all links `<td>` everything is displayed in center if it own. But I need to start all text at the same position. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understand is that you want to align the text.
Try this way, also try to be more exact and send us a copy of your code.
But from what i understood try out this.

```
    div style="text-align: center;">
<table style="margin: 0px auto;" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 1</td>
            <td>Cell 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 3</td>
            <td>Cell 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```